# Error in the for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab

I try to plot from for loop and I succeed in it(in small program) but when i try with a larger program, I get the following error:
***"{Error using ==> semilogy Not enough input arguments.
Error in ==> test6 at 27
    semilogy(pe1,'b',pe2,'r');}***
and i dont why 
I wish someone can have a look and help me

my code is

```
clc;
clear;
for n=0:45;

    n=n+1;
   q=55;
    w=42;
    r=-228.6;
    y(n+1)=n+34+w-q-r;
end 

b=36;
o=0.2;
x=b/(1+o);                        % RB for Bpsk
k=2*b/(1+o);                      % Rb for Qpsk
z=y-x;                            % Eb/No for Bpsk
m=y-k;                            % Eb/No for Qpsk
g=0; 
s=0;  
pe1= zeros(1, 47);
pe2= zeros(1, 47);

for i=0:45; 
    g=10.^(0.1*z);
    pe1=0.5*erfc(sqrt(g));
    s=10.^(0.1*m);
    pe2=0.5*erfc(sqrt(s));
end

semilogy(pe1,'b',pe2,'r');
xlabel('energy per bit per noise power spectral density (Eb/No) (dB) ');
ylabel('Bit error rate (Pe)');
legend('Bpsk','Qpsk');
grid;
```

Comment: I don't want to moralize, but your variable naming convention is awful I can't imagine returning to such code after a week or heavens forbid a month. Bunch of unnamed constants, one letter variable names. Get a grip man :)

Comment: sorry for my awful cod but im new in matlab programming so l try do my best to work with this program if you have more tips you can told me , this will be nice (more help in code)

Comment: if you have any knowledge about Qpsk,Bpsk  modulation this will help me

Answer (score 3):

The problem causing your error is that `semilogy` (like `plot`) expects inputs in the form `semilogy(X1,Y1,'b',X2,Y2,'r')` if you want to plot more than one line at the same time. So, your `semilogy` should be `semilogy(z,pe1,'b',m,pe2,'r')`. You also need the `z` and `m` in the `semilogy` call to get your x-axis scale correct.

You have a few other problems. I have not made it look exactly like I'd do it, since I wanted your code to be recognizable to you. But you may wish to compare your code line by line to the following. One thing I've done that is probably wrong is change `r` to its negative since otherwise `y` is far to large (so `pe1` and `pe2` were zero, via `erfc`).

Your code was already vectorized, so I got rid of the for loops. Note that you wouldn't have `n=n+1` in a `for n=` loop; it's incremented automatically.

```
clc;
clear;
n=0:45;
q=55;
w=42;
r=228.6;
y=n+34+w-q-r;

b=36;
o=0.2;
x=b/(1+o);                        % RB for Bpsk
k=2*b/(1+o);                      % Rb for Qpsk
z=y-x;                            % Eb/No for Bpsk
m=y-k;                            % Eb/No for Qpsk

g=10.^(0.1*z);
pe1=0.5*erfc(sqrt(g));
s=10.^(0.1*m);
pe2=0.5*erfc(sqrt(s));

semilogy(z,pe1,'b',m,pe2,'r');
xlabel('energy per bit per noise power spectral density (Eb/No) (dB) ');
ylabel('Bit error rate (Pe)');
legend('Bpsk','Qpsk');
grid;
```